# Neuralnetwork remove link to nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, neuralnetwork

I am using the neuralnetwork package to plot some forking pathways.
However, each time I plot, I  am encountering this strange issue with a line that starts above layer 1 (outside the nodes), and links to another layer.

I have this error **Package pgf Error: No shape named `L0-0' is known.**
But I am not sure how to fix it.
[image]

```
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}
\begin{neuralnetwork}[height=6, nodespacing=20mm, layerspacing=14mm, titlestyle = black, style=black]

    \newcommand{\nodeA}[2]{\ifnum #2=1 A \fi \ifnum #2=2 B \fi}
    \newcommand{\nodeB}[2]{\ifnum #2=1 C \fi \ifnum #2=2 D \fi}
    \newcommand{\nodeC}[2]{\ifnum #2=1 E \fi \ifnum #2=2 F \fi  \ifnum #2=3 G\fi}

    \hiddenlayercolor[layercolor=black!10,count=2, bias=false, title=\rotatebox{60}{\scriptsize{\textbf{Node 1 lag\hspace{4mm}}}}, text=\nodeA]
    \linklayers
    
    \hiddenlayercolor[layercolor=black!10,count=2, bias=false, title=\rotatebox{60}{\scriptsize{\textbf{Node 2\hspace{11mm}}}}, text=\nodeB]
    \linklayers

    \hiddenlayercolor[layercolor=black!10,count=3, bias=false, title=\rotatebox{60}{\scriptsize{\textbf{Node 3\hspace{11mm}}}}, text=\nodeC]
    \linklayers
    
    \outputlayer[count=2, text=\nodeA] 
    \linklayers

\end{neuralnetwork}
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting code snippets like this and edit your question to make it a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), so that we can just copy/paste and test it without having to figure out what to add to make it work.

Comment: Judging by the readme on the package's GitHub page, I'd start by removing the `\linklayer` command after the first `\hiddenlayercolor`. After all, the first layer can't be linked to a previous layer's nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation SebGlav. I thought this was a minimal example but I was wrong. And thank you @Qrrbrbirlbel. Actually, this code was reproducing the error from a larger plot. I removed all the \linklayers from the plot and put them back in the code, one by one. This erased the line.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Answer or close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `\linklayer` the first layer.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}
\begin{document}
\begin{neuralnetwork}[height=6, nodespacing=20mm, layerspacing=14mm]
\tikzset{
  hidden neuron/.append style={fill=black!10},
  my titlestyle/.style={
    rotate=60, text width=, anchor=south west, font=\scriptsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand{\nodeA}[2]{\ifnum #2=1 A \fi \ifnum #2=2 B \fi}
\newcommand{\nodeB}[2]{\ifnum #2=1 C \fi \ifnum #2=2 D \fi}
\newcommand{\nodeC}[2]{\ifnum #2=1 E \fi \ifnum #2=2 F \fi  \ifnum #2=3 G\fi}

\hiddenlayer[
  count=2, bias=false, text=\nodeA,
  title=Node 1 lag, titlestyle=my titlestyle]

\hiddenlayer[
  count=2, bias=false, text=\nodeB,
  title=Node 2, titlestyle=my titlestyle]
\linklayers

\hiddenlayer[
  count=3, bias=false, text=\nodeC,
  title=Node 3, titlestyle=my titlestyle]
\linklayers

\outputlayer[count=2, text=\nodeA]
\linklayers
\end{neuralnetwork}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]